# Capturing the Enter key in a TextBox

Tags: wpf

In my WPF view, I am trying to tie an event to the Enter key as follows:

```
<TextBox Width="240" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" Text="{Binding SearchCriteria, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
  <TextBox.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding EnterKeyCommand}"/>
      <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{Binding TabKeyCommand}"/>
  </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

This code works and my EnterKeyCommand fires when the users presses the Enter key. However, the problem is that when the event fires, WPF hasn't yet bound the text in the textbox to 'SearchCriteria'. So when my event fires, the contents of 'SearchCriteria' is blank. Is there a simple change I can make in this code so that I can get the contents of the textbox when my EnterKey command fires?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on your `TextBox.Text` binding to `PropertyChanged`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx).

Comment: Hi micahtan How can I capture Enter key in PreviewTextInput?

Comment: Hi @0MV1, the method outlined uses WPF binding.  If you'd like to use PreviewTextInput, you'll have to use event handling instead.

Comment: So, basically, he should change `Text="{Binding SearchCriteria, Mode=OneWayToSource}"` to `Text="{Binding SearchCriteria, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 25):

You can do this by passing the TextBox's `InputBindings` property as a `CommandParameter` to the `Command` :

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" 
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This was spot on!  This plus the info here, helped me through my confusion!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847860/how-to-call-method-in-window-xaml-cs-from-viewmodel-cs-without-introducing

Comment: I remain confused.  I put this in my text box, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is 6 years old but none of the answers produce the correct answer in its entirety using XAML and no code-behind.I still had some work to do. For reference the approach is the following. First the XAML

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SearchEnterHit}"/>
            <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding SearchEnterHit}"/>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
```

Basically the approach is that every key is tossed to the bound *SearchText* on every keystroke. Thus the string will be entirely present within SearchText once the return/enter is pressed. Thus in the *SearchEnterHit* command the entire string within the TextBox is available  via the SearchText property.

As mentioned above the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is what flushes every keystroke to the *SearchText* property. The KeyBindings capture the enter key.

This is really the simplest means of doing this with no code-behind and all XAML. Sure you are flushing keys to the SearchText property often but that generally is not a problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this in the code behind.

[How to: Detect When the Enter Key Pressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054(v=vs.110).aspx)

In the check for enter/return, just invoke your event handler code.

Comment: Code-behind should be generally avoided unless asbsolutely necessary.  An input binding is much more appropriate and declarative.

Answer (score 0):

It is also can be done like async event. 
Here is the example.

```
tbUsername.KeyDown += async (s, e) => await OnKeyDownHandler(s, e);  

private async Task OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Return)
   {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbUsername.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPassword.Password))
      {
          Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          await Login();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not completely true. The KeyDown event doesn't support async, so it will already continue executing before the async method is ready.