# Send TextBox KeyEventArgs value before exiting event

Tags: c#, wpf, keyeventargs

I have this:

```
 private void AssociatedObject_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
                {
                    textBox.SelectAll();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to:

1. Send the input value to its bound variable.
2. Highlight the input value in `TextBox`.

This code only highlights the input value but does not send the input value to the bound variable.

Comment: Hmm, "binded variable" is hard to see in that snippet.  Consider to also change the focus to another control.

Comment: Seeing the binded variable snippet would not help solve the issue. The binded variable is just the textbox.text. 

Changing Focus does not work because I want to keep focus on the textbos so I can highlight the text. Thank you.

Comment: I know, god forbid we'd get a snippet we can run ourselves.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556489/capturing-the-enter-key-in-a-textbox) shows how to do a better job of asking an SO question.  And surely is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: The question you provided shows how to capture and enter key event. I have already done that as shown on the code above. I want to be able to pass the input value while still highlighting the input value. Currently, with the code I have provided, I can only highlight the input value. But I cannot send the input value while highlighting the input value after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
 private void AssociatedObject_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
                {
                    BindingExpression b = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
                    if (b != null)
                    {
                        b.UpdateSource();
                    }

                    textBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```