# Capture Enter Key in a XAML Textbox Running in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, events, keydown

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Name Change" Height="260" Width="800"
        x:Name="Window">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtUPN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="32,155,0,0"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$upn = $Window.FindName('txtUPN')

$upn.Add_KeyDown(
    {if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$upn.Text | Out-Host}})

# KeyDown event fires, but doesn't capture the Enter key

$window.ShowDialog()
```

Using Powershell with a XAML GUI, I have 3 different textboxes that I would like to use the Enter key to trigger a function call, but nothing I come across seems to work.  Is there something I'm not seeing, some assembly missing?  Nothing seems to recognize Enter and I've even tried KeyChar on KeyPress. I'm not interested in a form window event, I prefer a textbox event. It seems to force you into using Buttons. Thanks.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556489/capturing-the-enter-key-in-a-textbox) and [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: if ($_.Key-eq "Return")

Answer (score 1):

keycode property worked fine in WinForms, but it seems in WPF you need to use key

```
$upn.Add_KeyDown(
{if ($_.Key -eq "Enter") 
{$upn.Text | Out-Host}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Mikel V. is correct.

I was looking for this solution, as I am updating a script from WinForms to XAML. Changing ".KeyCode" to ".Key" works correctly.

```
$TextBoxInput.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.Key -eq "Enter") {
        #do stuff
    }
})
```